# Icons in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, icons

I would like to know how to insert icons in visual studio code in an easy way while I'm programming. I saw some programmers that write something like :star: or :star and then an star appears in the code, I have been looking for some extensions but I didnt found something useful.

Greets.

Comment: Icons for what? Did they use them in a HTML side? For instance ````<span>star</span>````

Comment: You mean emojis?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see an emoji of a star typing :star. I have already created the visual code snippet like in the above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a snippet for this in the snippet file for the language you use

```
"star": {"prefix": ":star","body": [""],"description": "star char"}
```

You can set any char in the body string

Comment: Thanks!, How can I do to insert a downloaded image in body instead of ["*"] or if that is not possible I would like to have an emoji of a star or similar.

Comment: @GonWTC If it is a Unicode char you can copy paste it, i found it on https://emojipedia.org/glowing-star/

Comment: @GonWTC If you talk about downloaded image your talking about web applications or non unicode characters